# Upper and Lower Case Combination Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, uppercase, lowercase

I have a string of data where EXpC means Airplane and EXPC means Airplane Parts, but in Power BI is recognizing all as airplane, how do i deal with this?

I try many ways but is not working

Comment: EXpC means Airplane, and EXPC means Airplane Parts, and also placing them as Uppwer Case like: EXPC Airplane and EXPC Airplane Parts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is case insensitive. Unlike Power Query - very confusing! However, it should be enough to replace these strings in Power Query so that they are distinguishable by the Power BI engine.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click "Transform Data" in Power BI (this opens Power Query)
2. Navigate to the "Transform" Tab
3. Select the column that contains these `EXpC` and `EXPC` values
4. Select "Replace Value" and replace e.g. `EXpC` with `Airplane`
5. Select "Replace Value" again and replace e.g. `EXPC` with `Airplane Parts`
6. Click Save and Load to reload your data into the Power BI data model

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but how do I do that in Power BI

Comment: I have amended my answer to include a step-by-step solution

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, but there are over 1000 mixes with simular situations; I will post again with a more detailed question. Thank you again